# Phpspreadsheet : Download doesn't work for .csv and .pdf files

Tags: excel, file, download, phpspreadsheet

I work with the Symfony 4 framework. My goal is to be able to export data with different possible formats (**xlsx, ods, csv, pdf**).

In my controller, I did like this:

```php
    /**
         * Permet d'exporter des données.
         *
         * @Route("rh/export", name="rh_export")
         */
        public function export(Request $request, ExportService $exportService)
        {
            $exportExcel = new ExportExcel();

            $form = $this->createForm(ExportExcelType::class, $exportExcel);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $spreadsheet = $exportService->export($exportExcel);

                switch($exportExcel->getExtension())
                {
                    case "xlsx":
                        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
                    break;

                    case "csv":
                        $writer = new Csv($spreadsheet);
                    break;

                    case "ods":
                        $writer = new Ods($spreadsheet);
                    break;

                    case "pdf":
                        $writer = new Dompdf($spreadsheet);
                    break;

                    default:
                        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
                    break;
                }

                if($exportExcel->getExtension() === "pdf")
                {
                    $writer->writeAllSheets();
                }

                // Create a Temporary file in the system
                $fileName = $exportExcel->getNomFichier().'.' . $exportExcel->getExtension();
                $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName);

                // Create the excel file in the tmp directory of the system
                $writer->save($temp_file);

                // Return the excel file as an attachment
                return $this->file($temp_file, $fileName, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
            }

            return $this->render('rh/export.html.twig', [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ]);
        }
```

1. I analyze the submission of the form.
2. I create the spreadsheet
3. Depending on the type of file desired, I initialize the $writer
4. Create a Temporary file in the system
5. Create the excel file in the tmp directory of the system
6. Return the excel file as an attachment

The strange thing is that when the file type is .xlsx or .ods, the file downloads correctly.
However if it is .csv or .pdf, then the file is not downloaded, and instead it opens in my browser

EDIT : I resolved my problem with :

Replace :

```php
 // Create a Temporary file in the system
                $fileName = $exportExcel->getNomFichier().'.' . $exportExcel->getExtension();
                $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName);

                // Create the excel file in the tmp directory of the system
                $writer->save($temp_file);

                // Return the excel file as an attachment
                return $this->file($temp_file, $fileName, ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
```

by

```php
$response =  new StreamedResponse(
                function () use ($writer) {
                    $writer->save('php://output');
                }
            );

            $fileName = $exportExcel->getNomFichier().'.' . $exportExcel->getExtension();
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment;filename="%s"', $fileName));
            $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','max-age=0');
            return $response;
```

Comment: Whether or not a file is downloaded or handled by the browser is something that is controlled by the user and depends on the browser. You don't have any direct control over whether or not a file is downloaded or opened in the browser.

Comment: I updated my first post with the solution

Comment: That may work in some cases but it's still up to the user and their browser settings whether or not something is downloaded or opened directly.